# How to store value of variables and use them in the next for loop iteration

Tags: swift, for-loop, variables, swiftui

This is the 2nd to 7th columns of a table with 150 rows, and I separated it to a new file for easier reading and maintenance.
Within the for loop, the variables should update and be stored for the next loop iteration, after the logic run; but now the variables are reset after one iteration.
How to make the variables can be stored for the next loop iteration?

```
import SwiftUI
class StockSymbol1Data: ObservableObject {
    
    let secondaryRally = 1
    let naturalRally = 2
    let upwardTrend = 3
    let downwardTrend = 4
    let naturalReaction = 5
    let secondaryReaction = 6
    
    @Published var currentColumn: Double?
    @Published  var lastUpwardTrend: Double?
    @Published  var lastSecondaryRally: Double?
    @Published  var lastSecondaryReaction: Double?
    @Published  var lastNaturalRally: Double?
    @Published  var lastNaturalReaction: Double?
    @Published  var lastDownwardTrend: Double?
    @Published  var blackLineDownwardTrend: Double?
    @Published  var blackLineNaturalRally: Double?
    @Published  var redLineUpwardTrend: Double?
    @Published  var redLineNaturalReaction: Double?
}
struct StockSymbol1ColumnView: View {
    let close1: Double
    let headers: [String]
    let scrollViewWidth: CGFloat

    let priceMovePts: Double = 6
    let furtherPriceMovePts: Double = 3
    @ObservedObject var stockSymbol1Data: StockSymbol1Data
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<6, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
            let columnClose: Double? = {
                switch columnIndex {
                case 0:
                    // Apply your rule here for Secondary Rally column
            return stockSymbol1Data.lastSecondaryReaction == close1 ? close1 : nil
        case 1:
                    // Apply your rule here for Natural Rally column
            return stockSymbol1Data.lastNaturalRally == close1 ? close1 : nil
        case 2:
                    // Apply your rule here for Upward Trend column
            return stockSymbol1Data.lastUpwardTrend == close1 ? close1 : nil
        case 3:
                    // Apply your rule here for DownwardTrend column
            return stockSymbol1Data.lastDownwardTrend == close1 ? close1 : nil
        case 4:
                    // Apply your rule here for NaturalReaction column
            return stockSymbol1Data.lastNaturalReaction == close1 ? close1 : nil
        case 5:
                    // Apply your rule here for Secondary Reaction column
             return stockSymbol1Data.lastSecondaryReaction == close1 ? close1 : nil
                    return nil
                }
            }()

            let textColor: Color = {
                switch columnIndex {
                case 2:
                    // Change text color for Upward Trend column to black
                    return .black
                case 3:
                    // Change text color forDownward Trend column to red
                    return .red
                default:
                    return .gray
                }
            }()

            Text(columnClose != nil ? "\(columnClose ?? 0.0)" : "")
                .frame(width: scrollViewWidth / CGFloat(headers.count), height: 15)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 2)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                .foregroundColor(textColor)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding Self. method or something else, but the new loop iteration just reset the variables and cannot get the results and updates of the previous loop. I want the variables to be updated in one loop iteration and can be referred in the subsequent loop iterations.

Comment: A ForEach isn’t really a loop it just iterates over the collection presenting views, in a traditional loop the iterations happen one after the other in a ForEach they are presenting at the same time any calculations should be ready to display when the ForEach renders. Views are for UI not “work”.

Comment: Thanks for your comment..but the issue is the variables cannot carry forward to the next row.. how to fix it?

Comment: Create a "ConfigModel" or a "ListModel" a `struct` that does all the math and holds everything you need that way the `ForEach` can just display.

Comment: Thank you..because on the first column of the table, it is the dates, and the values of close1 are based on the dates, so the logic block should be within the ForEach… the issue remains the same after separate the logic to another file and it is called within the ForEach.. the variables are reset on each new row, but I want to keep the updates of variables on eqch row and use them to compare with the new close1 value on the subsequent rows.. That’s how the logic runs, the logic mainly compares the updated variables to the new close1 on that date

Comment: We know exactly what you are trying to do, that isn’t the issue. The issue is that you expect that ForEach has the ability to do what you want, you have to create the logic, you have to prepare the data so it is ready to display by the ForEach.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum . I am trying to store the updated variables on this row and sent the updated variables back to the logic block on the next row.. is it the right direction?

Comment: var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<6, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
            let columnClose: Double? = {
                stockSymbol1Logic.processRow(close1)
                switch columnIndex {
                                case 0:
                                    // Apply your rule here for Secondary Rally column
                            return stockSymbol1Logic.lastSecondaryReaction == close1 ? close1 : nil
I have added stockSymbol1Logic.swift  file and this is how it called in ForEach loop.. should i make a .onchange block on this Column View file and store value?

Comment: I don’t think I can be anymore help here. You aren’t following my advise and your code isn’t an MRE I could work with.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood your meaning..can you give a sample code so to have the same picture with us?